# How should I paint/color my Revan fx lightsaber green button to black?

Tags: material-selection, painting

Attached is a picture of my Hasbro Revan lightsaber. It's almost accurate to the actual hilt of the Knights of the Old Republic game. The one thing I want to change is the green button and make it black. What materials do I need or is highly suggested?

Thank you[image: Hasbro Revan FX Elite Lightsaber]

Comment: Does that portion easily come apart, like being held together only by screws so you can open it up without risk of damaging it? If those buttons are self-contained switches, you would be limited to painting it, which doesn't hold up well to wear. But often, the silver ring around the button is a separate bezel, and the button is a plastic cap that pushes on a switch or contacts below it. In that case, you could mold a thin rimmed dome of black silicone rubber to fit over the button and under the bezel.

Comment: The part does not come off unfortunately

Comment: It would help if it's possible to make an educated guess as to the kind of plastic used in the button.  Some will take paint and on others, paint would easily peel off.  Is the plastic hard (can you make a dent pressing a finger nail into it? If you tap it with your finger nail, does it make a sharp "tick" sound or a dull sound?). Polystyrene or ABS are shiny like that and hard, and will take paint, especially paints designed for plastic, with hydrocarbon solvents. Polypropylene is also shiny like that but softer, and paint won't bond to it.

Comment: I wish I could the plastic decently hard but that green button is really meant to just tap a few times.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on how much you're going to be touching the button, hobbyist enamel paint (applied with a brush) could work. You can sand the surface of the button first if you're worried about adhesion. I've found Testors brand works pretty well. They sell it at hobby craft stores and art supply stores in very small jars in the US.

I'd suggest covering the area around the button with blue tape or masking tape, to prevent messes